# Probability of getting 2 ripe mangoes in two different metthods

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **Question:** A bag contains $10$ mangoes out of which only $6$ are ripe. Two mangoes are taken out together.If one of them is ripe then what is the probability that the other one is ripe as well $?$

Now, all possible cases is definitely $\binom {10}{2}.$ I think the favourable cases could be found in two ways.

$i)$ the question means $2$ ripe mangoes are picked up. So favourable cases are $\binom{6}{2}=15$

$ii)$ $1$ ripe mango can be chosen in $6$ ways. For each such case, the second mango can be chosen from the rest of the $5$ ripe mangoes in $5$ ways that is $6\times 5=30$.

One of the reasoning is wrong obviously. Which one and how? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: This is a conditional probability, which means that the total number of sample points should be reduced. Given that one of the two mangoes is ripe, the total number of possible cases is no longer $10\choose{2}$.

Comment: No of ways one of them is ripe is 6.  P(One is ripe) $=\frac{6}{10}$.  Given that one is ripe, the number of ways the other is ripe is 5.  P(other is ripe/one is ripe) $=\frac{5}{9}$.  Now multiply, thus the answer is $=\frac{30}{90}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: The problem says that we are given that one of the mangoes is ripe, so P(one is ripe) = 1. The probability that the other is ripe is slightly less than $\frac{5}{9}$, following a logic similar to that used for the Monty Hall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional probability: $$P(\mbox{the other one is ripe}|\mbox{at least one is ripe}) = \frac{P(\mbox{both are ripe})}{P(\mbox{at least one is ripe})}=\frac{\frac{6 \choose 2} {10 \choose2}} {\frac{{6 \choose 1}{4 \choose1}+{6 \choose 2}}{10 \choose 2}}=\frac{15}{39}=\frac{5}{13}.$$

Comment: are sure about the formula you used?

Comment: @user118494 It's not right! Thank you for pointing that out, I'm going to correct it right now. I fell victim to my too short descriptions. :)

Comment: @user118494 As far as your question goes, if you pick $\Omega={10 \choose 2}$ then option **i** is correct as the **order** of choosing is neglected. Note that if you want to look at the problem as you proposed in **ii** your $\Omega$ then would be $10 \cdot 9$.